# Clojure: How does (reader "/tmp/test.txt") result in a BufferedReader

Tags: clojure, io

I was trying to understand the following snippet of code.

```
use 'clojure.java.io)
(with-open [rdr (reader "/tmp/test.txt")]
  (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
    (println line)))
```

Though I can follow it at a reasonably level of fidelity I have trouble figuring out how (reader "/tmp/test.txt") result in a BufferedReader

When I search on reader and clojure I get [this](http://clojure.org/reader)

In the same vane, is there a good treatment of Clojure IO -- the [Java trails I read on Java IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) were an excellent treatment of the subject. However I have had trouble finding a similarly succinct treatment of IO on Clojure. Unfortunately on Clojure one challenge has been that I find stuff in a very fragmented manner.

EDIT:
As one of the posters has pointed out that the two readers are different -- I was aware of that -- the point I was trying to make was that I had a hard time finding the correct documentation for reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention two different kinds of readers in your post. The `reader` method is part of the `java.io` namespace, and you can check the [clojure.java.io/reader](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.java.io-api.html#clojure.java.io/reader) API documentation to see what it does:

> Usage: (reader x & opts) Attempts to coerce its argument into an open
>   java.io.Reader. Default implementations always return a
>   java.io.BufferedReader.
>
> Default implementations are provided for Reader, BufferedReader,
>   InputStream, File, URI, URL, Socket, byte arrays, character arrays,
>   and String.
>
> If argument is a String, it tries to resolve it first as a URI, then
>   as a local file name.  URIs with a 'file' protocol are converted to
>   local file names.
>
> Should be used inside with-open to ensure the Reader is properly
>   closed.

The *reader* turned up by your Google search is Clojure's implementation of the [Lisp reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_reader). The Lisp reader is what parses Clojure syntax and lets you do dynamic things like [read](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/read) and [eval](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/eval) at runtime.

---

As for the second half of your question, I don't think there's a definitive source on I/O in Clojure. Since Clojure runs on the JVM and has full Java interop, I think your best bet is just reading through the Java Trails tutorial, then looking at the [clojure.java.io API](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.java.io-api.html). For anything that's not nicely wrapped in the API you can either write your own wrappers, or just access the Java classes directly using Clojure syntax.